# compare multiple vectors of different lengths, count the elements that are the same, and print out those that are the same and different

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have five vectors with the following format, and of varying lengths. The are vectors of single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs)

```
A <- c("2179_39","2764_47","4521_24","9056_66")
B <- c("2478_39","2734_47","4531_24","2178_39","2734_47","4521_24")
```

In R, I would like to:
pint out which SNPs match between the different vectors
count the number of SNPs that match
print out which SNPs do not match
count the number of SNPs that do not match

I found the following script that prints out the locations where the vectors match, but I've tried a bunch of print and length functions in it, and I can't seems to get what I really want from it. I'd also like to iterate through my five vectors (i.e., A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, A vs E, etc...) if possible.

```
foo <- function(A,B){
  if (!isTRUE(all.equal(A,B))){
    mismatches <- paste(which(A != B), collapse = ",")
    stop(mismatches )
  } else {
    message("Yahtzee!")
  }
}

foo(A,B)
```

Any advice, even just a site to look at to help me integrate the print and length functions, would be great.

Ella

Answer (score 1):

```
compare.SNPs <- function(A, B) {
  # consider only unique names
  A.u <- unique(A)
  B.u <- unique(B)
  common.A.B <- intersect(A.u, B.u)
  diff.A.B <- setdiff(A.u, B.u)
  diff.B.A <- setdiff(B.u, A.u)
  uncommon.A.B <- union(diff.A.B, diff.B.A)
  cat(paste0("The sets have ", length(common.A.B), " SNPs in common:"))
  print(common.A.B)
  print(paste0("The sets have ", length(uncommon.A.B), " SNPs not in common:"))
  print(paste0("In the first set, but not in the second set:"))
  print(diff.A.B)
  print(paste0("Not in the first set, but in the second set:"))
  print(diff.B.A)

}

compare.SNPs(A, B)

The sets have 1 SNPs in common:[1] "4521_24"
[1] "The sets have 7 SNPs not in common:"
[1] "In the first set, but not in the second set:"
[1] "2179_39" "2764_47" "9056_66"
[1] "Not in the first set, but in the second set:"
[1] "2478_39" "2734_47" "4531_24" "2178_39"
```