# compare multiple vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I would like to extend what is working with [compare multiple vectors of different lengths, count the elements that are the same, and print out those that are the same and different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380588/compare-multiple-vectors-of-different-lengths-count-the-elements-that-are-the-s/50381367#50381367). I'd like to write a loop so that I can do pairwise comparisons of ten different vectors to find which is in common for each comparison, for all possible pairwise options. The main comparison part of the below pseudo-code is working, and from the previous post, but this is just to compare A and B, and I would like to compare A to C, A to #D, B to C, etc...

```
vectors to be compared: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J
set global variable for first vector to be compared
set global variable for second vector to be compared

#vetors -- these are subsets of my real vectors, which are more like 50 - 200 elements long
A <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
        "2776_77",  "3049_79", "3084_15",  "3995_78", "4066_33", "4431_15")
B <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
       "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_15",  "3995_78")
C <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1910_79", "1972_76", "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_14",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
D <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
      "2773_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_12",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
E <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
      "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_17", "4431_19", "4885_78")
F <- c("868_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
       "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_15",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
G <- c("866_78", "1837_78", "1721_78", "1972_76", "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_15",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
H <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
        "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_15",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
I <- c("866_78", "1137_28", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
       "2776_77",  
       "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")
J <- c("866_78", "1137_78", "1721_78", "1745_79", "1910_79", "1972_76", 
       "2776_77",  
       "3049_79", "3084_18",  "3995_78", "4066_36", "4431_19", "4885_78")

for(i ???)
{
compare.SNPs <- function(A, B) {
  # consider only unique names
  A.u <- unique(A)
  B.u <- unique(B)
  common.A.B <- intersect(A.u, B.u)
  diff.A.B <- setdiff(A.u, B.u)
  diff.B.A <- setdiff(B.u, A.u)
  uncommon.A.B <- union(diff.A.B, diff.B.A)
  cat(paste0("The sets have ", length(common.A.B), " SNPs in common:"))
  print(common.A.B)
  print(paste0("The sets have ", length(uncommon.A.B), " SNPs not in 
  common:"))
  print(paste0("In the first set, but not in the second set:"))
  print(diff.A.B)
  print(paste0("Not in the first set, but in the second set:"))
  print(diff.B.A)

}
compare.SNPs(A,B)
}
```

Any guidance for example code to look at would be much appreciated.

Sincerely,
Ella

Comment: I'm not sure that creating A.u and B.u is necessary - the set operations remove duplicates, as far as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

```
xx<-combn(LETTERS[1:10],2)
for (i in 1:dim(xx)[2]) {
      cat(paste0("Comparing ", xx[1,i], " and ", xx[2,i],": "))
      compare.SNPs(get(xx[1,i]),get(xx[2,i]))
    }
```

(Also, no reason for the `function()` call to be inside the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

First you should tell your function `compare.SNPs` to give you something.. well.. in `return` instead of just printing. This is done with `return(list(common.A.B, diff.A.B, diff.B.A))`

```
compare.SNPs <- function(A, B) {
  # consider only unique names
  A.u <- unique(A)
  B.u <- unique(B)
  common.A.B <- intersect(A.u, B.u)
  diff.A.B <- setdiff(A.u, B.u)
  diff.B.A <- setdiff(B.u, A.u)
  uncommon.A.B <- union(diff.A.B, diff.B.A)
  cat(paste0("The sets have ", length(common.A.B), " SNPs in common:"))
  print(common.A.B)
  print(paste0("The sets have ", length(uncommon.A.B), " SNPs not in 
               common:"))
  print(paste0("In the first set, but not in the second set:"))
  print(diff.A.B)
  print(paste0("Not in the first set, but in the second set:"))
  print(diff.B.A)
  return(list(common.A.B, diff.A.B, diff.B.A))
}
```

So now this function will `return` you a `list` with 3 elements: the common elements of the two vectors, then the 2 sets of differences.

```
mylist <- list(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)
allcomparisons <- list()
for(i in 1:length(mylist))
{
  for(j in 1:length(mylist)) {
    allcomparisons <- c(allcomparisons, compare.SNPs(mylist[[i]], mylist[[j]]))
  }
}
```

Comparing A to J is comparing 10x10 elements, which will give you 300 elements in total: first the common elements of A and A, then the difference between A and A, then again difference between A and A, then the common elements of A and B and so on.
You can then access the elements of `allcomparisons` like any other list. For example you can check that `all(allcomparisons[[4]]==compare.SNPs(A,B)[[1]])`

```
[1] TRUE
```